# POS for .Net can not detect printer

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, pos-for-.net

I am using POS for .Net framework version 1.12 for one of my project.

Microsoft POS for .NET is a class library that is part of Microsoft Windows Embedded for Point of Service.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms828083%28v=winembedded.10%29.aspx

```
    private PosPrinter GetReceiptPrinter()
    {
        PosExplorer posExplorer = new PosExplorer(this);
        DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter);
        return (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(receiptPrinterDevice);
    }
```

above is the sample code for find the printer. Now my issue is that POS is not able to detect the printer but only open simulator with data when i run my application.

can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Is your printer details(LDN) getting added to the configuration file??

Answer (score 1):

I had developed an application for a POS running Windows CE as the operating System but for that POS, the manufacturer provided a custom dll for invoking the operations of the printer which I consumed in my C# code. Check with the POS manufacturer and see if they are providing custom dll for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your line of code

```
DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter);
```

will return the **default** or **first** PosPrinter found, which in your case looks like it is the simulator.

You need to either **(1)** Iterate over the collection of printers and *somehow* select the one you want. i.e.

```
foreach (DeviceInfo deviceInfo in explorer.GetDevices(DeviceType.PosPrinter))
{
    if (isThisThePrinterIWant(deviceInfo))   // user defined function (maybe lookup saved preference file)
    {
        return (PosPrinter)posExplorer.CreateInstance(deviceInfo );
    }
} // Note: GetDevices() not GetDevice()
```

or **(2)** Set a logical name for your printer (using software that came with your printer, or the POSDM utility included with Pos for .Net SDK) and change the above line to

```
DeviceInfo receiptPrinterDevice = posExplorer.GetDevice(DeviceType.PosPrinter, "madeUpLogicalName");
```

or **(3)** Simply set the desired printer as the default printer, and leave your code the way it is.